# How to stop email subscription from report server based on certain event?

Tags: reporting-services, data-warehouse, reportserver

I want to stop subscription from report server based on certain event.

I have tried updating `EndDate` column of the subscription table to disable the subscription, but the updated `EndDate` is not reflecting when I see the subscription from share point. When I update `EndDate` from SharePoint it gets reflected in subscription table of report server.

Is there any way to achieve this? How can I programatically stop the report server e-mail subscription based on certain event?

Comment: What kind of event? Can the event be identified with a query?

Answer (score 1):

You can update EndDate by calling SetSubscriptionProperties ( see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2006.reportingservice2006.setsubscriptionproperties.aspx )

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Is it possible to update the Subscription table directly using sql update query since the event generated can be identified by sql query.
I need to achieve this using SSIS.

Thanks,

Comment: You can call a method from SSIS using a script task. Why not just do that?